# Python package installation issue : PyAudio and PortAudio

Tags: python

I tried installing `pyaudio` from various source such as pip, conda, whl file, unofficial python, pyaudio.exe but none of them worked.
When I write:

```
conda install pyaudio
```

it says **All requested packages already installed**.

I went to lib of anaconda and there I found `pyaudio.py` but then also I cannot import it in my program.

Comment: Is your code in the same conda environment where you installed the library?

Answer (score 1):

Please install pyaudio using pipwin.

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```